# How to create dummy data in a newly created developer org

Tags: sandbox

Is there any automation where we can create dummy data for a newly created org. If i have a excel sheet with multiple sheets in it. Like Account, Contact, Opportunity can we import it.

Comment: Is this a new sandbox for an existing org or a completely new Org? If it is completely new you only have the option of importing the data from Excel by saving into .csv files for each tab then using Data Loader or the Data Import wizard to load it.

Comment: And if it is for existing org how to automate it..

Comment: Have a look at the Answer Mihai provided, also Full Copy sandbox automatically takes all data from production or Partial Copy sandbox can take a snapshot of some production data. Otherwise you are pretty much stuck with uploading even if you automate the upload.

Answer (score 7):

You could take advantage of the new feature to run a script when a sandbox is created or refreshed. You can find details about the [feature](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_deployment_sandbox_postcopy_script.htm) in the latest release notes. I would run some apex code that will insert generic accounts or contacts or call an external system that has that spreadsheet uploaded or even a database.

Comment: How to use Run Script After Sandbox Creation and Refresh for creating accounts, contacts and opportunity.. Can u share some code if u hv..

Comment: I don't have any example of a code. But if you look at the release notes, there is an example. You then need to create an Apex class that creates 100 Account, then 200 Contacts and link them and so on. It's basically Apex, and inserting Accounts and Contacts

Comment: Hi, where we need to write the interface..

Comment: It will be on the class you specify in the user interface that will be run as part of the post copy event